# Whom shall we design for either "Manager" OR "Sales Representative" OR "User"?

Tags: ux-field, user-centered-design, ux-designer, ux-integration

There are lots of frictions when we a thought process in terms of design. As during a design process, such many things happen in our real world like **"I do not like your color combination or designs layouts. Check an example having these wxy.com has such features I need better than that - Manager (has a thought in terms of developers)".**

**Whom are we designing for? Is it for the managers who is handling or for the users who is going to use it?**

When the design process is not being followed, it's tough to have decisions to bring all relatives methods of design to bring in such environment.

My Questions is that, in such scenarios how to have all the design process where I can focus on my future.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, we want to design for the user. That usually involves taking a stand against the client's project owner and even your own team.

In the real world we often lose those battles and we end up designing to please the client. (In my experience they claim to know the user, so they don't want us to spend time and budget on research and discovery. They rarely know the things about users that we need to know.) So a lot of the time you do your best to make decisions as well as you can, given the information you have.

In the long run, your best bet is to educate the people on your team and others in your organization about the benefits of designing for users. So then your team can speak as one to clients who insist on taking over your design process.

When in your situation, I usually point out that our design is geared toward the client's users, and wxy.com is designed for a different type of user. (If, in fact, that's true.)

Comment: yes, it is true in real world.

Comment: A nice comparison to get the managers and designers to realise that they are 'too close' to the project, is the example of proofreading: it can be very difficult to spot errors in your own copy as you see what you thought you have written, rather than what is actually on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Management's vision of an application can come from several sources, such as business requirements, user enhancement requests, and so on. Since it's usually impossible to cater to every users' individual requests, some compromise is usually necessary anyways, and it is usually best to let management be the arbiter of those compromises. In other words, with good management, we're actually catering to the majority of the intended users, while with less competent management, we may very well simply be catering to their whims. If there's any concerns, we should definitely ask and/or suggest alternatives, but management is usually paying the bills, so their decision is final. It is usually within our expected duties to question management, but not refuse their requests.